# How to read Hadoop Map intermediate file file.out

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I have set property  `keep.task.files.pattern` to `".*"` in mapred-site.xml

restarted cluster and executed my test mapreduce program.

I see two file file.out and file.out.index in the folder
`/opt/hadoopws/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201403260903_0001/attempt_201403260903_0001_m_000000_0/output/`

When i attempt to read file.out using below code i get `"not a SequenceFile error"` message.
I know for sure its a binary file when i try to open file.out with less, it prompts that its a binary file.
I'm running Hadoop 1.2.1. What is the default map output format?

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = new Path("/opt/hadoopws/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache
             /job_201403260903_0001/attempt_201403260903_0001_m_000000_0/output
             /file.out");
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);
IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
IntWritable value = new IntWritable();
while (reader.next(key, value)) {
        System.out.println(key.get() + " | " + value.get());
    }
reader.close();
```

---

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: /opt/hadoopws/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201403260903_0001/attempt_201403260903_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out not a SequenceFile
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1517)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1490)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1479)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1474)
at HDPConfigRun.run(HDPConfigRun.java:31)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at HDPConfigRun.main(HDPConfigRun.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is similar to a sequential file in that it contains key value pairs persisted in their serialized form, but it's designed to be scanned quickly for sort and partitioning purposes and has an internal-only format.

If you really need to see the set of key value pairs produced by the mapper then look into configuring your reducer to use the MultipleOutputs class - one output would contain every key/value pair read in by the reducer and another output to contain the "real" output of the reducer.

Comment: if we cant read the file what is the point in saving intermediate files and the use of property  keep.task.files.pattern

Comment: I suspect that it's more an internal debugging option.  I've never heard of a use case for hadoop that involves the use of that file.